# Getting Error in loss function while training a model in Pytorch?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I am new to Machine Learning and trying my hands on a categorization problem. While training the model in pytorch I am getting following error. Any help on the topic is much appreciated.

Error: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-



import numpy  as np

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def makeData(A,B,C,numOfSamples,blur):
    a = [A[0] + np.random.randn(numOfSamples)*blur,A[1] + np.random.randn(numOfSamples)*blur]
    b = [B[0] + np.random.randn(numOfSamples)*blur,B[1] + np.random.randn(numOfSamples)*blur]
    c = [C[0] + np.random.randn(numOfSamples)*blur,C[1] + np.random.randn(numOfSamples)*blur]
    

    data_np = np.hstack((a,b,c)).T
    
    processed = np.array([np.sin(data_np[:,0]),np.cos(data_np[:,1])])
    
    
    
    #data_np = np.append(data_np,processed.T,axis=1)
    #print(data_np.shape)
    labels_np = np.vstack((np.zeros((numOfSamples,1)),np.ones((numOfSamples,1)),1+np.ones((numOfSamples,1))))

    data = torch.tensor(data_np).float()
    labels = torch.tensor(labels_np).float()
    
    return (data,labels)

def buildAndTrain(data,labels):
    model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(2,4),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(4, 3),
            #nn.ReLU(),
            #nn.Linear(64, 3),
            nn.Softmax(dim=1)
            
        )
    lossfun = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr = 0.01)
    
    epochs = 1000
    ongoingAccuracy = np.zeros(epochs)
    for i in range(epochs):
        yHat = model(data)
        
        
        loss = lossfun(yHat,labels)
        
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        
        accuracy = torch.mean((torch.argmax(yHat,axis = 1)==labels).float())*100
        print(accuracy)
        
    
    

A = [1,1]
B = [5,7]
C = [-2,3]

numOfSamples = 100
blur = 1

data, labels = makeData(A,B,C,numOfSamples,blur)

buildAndTrain(data,labels)

plt.plot(data[np.where(labels == 0)[0],0],data[np.where(labels == 0)[0],1],'rs')
plt.plot(data[np.where(labels == 1)[0],0],data[np.where(labels == 1)[0],1],'bs')
plt.plot(data[np.where(labels == 2)[0],0],data[np.where(labels == 2)[0],1],'ks')
```

Please let me know if any more details are required.

Full Stack error

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\prakh\Documents\tutorials\python\pytorch\ann6.py", line 77, in 
buildAndTrain(data,labels)

File "C:\Users\prakh\Documents\tutorials\python\pytorch\ann6.py", line 56, in buildAndTrain
loss = lossfun(yHat,labels)

File "C:\Users\prakh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1102, in _call_impl
return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\prakh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\loss.py", line 1150, in forward
return F.cross_entropy(input, target, weight=self.weight,

File "C:\Users\prakh\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 2846, in cross_entropy
return torch._C._nn.cross_entropy_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index, label_smoothing)

RuntimeError: 0D or 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported

Comment: Please include the full trace stack for the error you're getting

Comment: How are your labels formatted? are they perhaps 'one hot'? From the line where you create `labels_np` it seems that you have multiple labels for each sample which is not supported by `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. You can create multiple CrossEnthropy losses for each target and then add them together/take average,etc.